# two Anchored VWAP from specific day of past months

Tags: loops, tradingview-api, indicator

I want two anchored vWAP plot

1. first anchored vWAP plot from last Friday of each month (repeat the cycle from last Friday of last month to last Friday of current month).
2. second anchored VWAP from last Friday of "second last month" to last Friday of current month. (repeat the cycle (loop) once current date pass the last Friday of month)

I only get success in first anchored vWAP(below code),  but for second one it is too difficult. Anyone help me for coding in pine script version 5.

```
//@version=5

indicator("AVWAP", "AVWAP_2", overlay = true)

// Loop through all the days of a month.
var lf = array.new_float(0)

get_last_friday_of_month(mth = month) =>
    for i = 1 to 31
        // Check to see if the day is a Friday, and make sure we're not overflowing into next month. 
        if dayofweek(timestamp(year, mth, i, 0, 0, 0)) == 6 and month(timestamp(year, mth, i, 0, 0, 0)) == mth 
            // Store that date for the moment 
            array.push(lf, timestamp(year, mth, i, 0, 0, 0))
    // The last value in the array is the last Friday.        
    array.get(lf, array.size(lf) - 1)

// Store the last Friday to use in the next step.
var last_friday = get_last_friday_of_month(month)


// If today's date is past the last Friday, find the last Friday of past month.
last_friday := time > last_friday ? get_last_friday_of_month(month): last_friday


start_time_1 = last_friday

before_time_range_1 = time < start_time_1

start_time_range_1 = time >= start_time_1 and time[1] < start_time_1

float sumpv_1 = na
float sumv_1 = na
sumpv_1 := start_time_range_1 ? hlc3 * volume : sumpv_1[1] + hlc3 * volume
sumv_1 := start_time_range_1 ? volume : sumv_1[1] + volume

avwap_1 = sumpv_1 / sumv_1

plot(avwap_1, color=color.rgb(250, 250, 250))
```

I am noly able get anchored vwap plot from last friday of previous month to current month in repeat cycle form. but I also need another anchored vwap from last friday previous to previous month. It should break on last friday of each month and again plot from last friday of previous to previous month.

ABvbe code should do automatic loop break. I have already done with manual input timestamp tab but i need it complete automatic.